# Why are people making up tags when we have one?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

People are making up new tags to mean the same thing. There needs to be a definitive tag for each meaning.

Search for "multi" in Tags. Find:

- [multiple-monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors) x12
- [multiscreen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiscreen) x3
- [multi-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-monitor) x2

Therefore I suggest multiple-monitors be the de facto standard and someone with sufficient rep retag the others. Let's nip this thing in the bud before it gets to be a problem on ALL stackware websites.

Because this has to be a question:  Why are people making up tags when we have one?

This goes for other areas as well. I'm sure this is more prevalent than I realize.

BTW I suggest adding this to sufaq-official tag, but not sure if "official" implies a process.

Comment: It's _much_ more prevalent than you realize.  For some reason people just don't pay good attention to the suggestion prompts, or don't understand the purpose tagging.

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes wonder if everybody sees the suggestions while typing the tags. What if people type faster than the Ajax suggestion displays? (Or: slow connection, slow computer, something blocking Ajax requests, or no JavaScript at all?)

(Likewise, I was surprised to learn that some wanted [to make it easier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39632/easier-to-close-questions-as-a-duplicate) to close questions as duplicates, while for me pasting the full URL is all I need to get some JavaScript magic started right away.)

Answer (score 2):

> Why are people making up tags when we have one?

To get a badge...

Answer (score 1):

Meta is where we spend a bit of time hashing out what the proper tag conventions are. Once a convention is decided upon, the users and the moderators are expected to try and abide by it. Obviously there are going to be some misses here and there by people who are not as familiar with things as others.

Anybody with over 500 rep can retag questions, so it will not be long before a lot of the copy-cat tags start getting whittled down.

Comment: In fact, the whittling has begun!

Comment: TXI, shouldn't you be mod here too?  Since you are on SU.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was a bug tracker :)

Comment: jinguy: I should be made a mod on Meta after about a week. I think I am under a "probationary" moderator period right now.

Comment: Well, good luck and don't screw it up.

Comment: Congratulations and good luck on making moderator.

Comment: Thanks bill, I'll try to do my best.

Answer (score 1):

Some multis merged:

- multi-platform/multiplatform => [cross-platform](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cross-platform)
- multicore/multiple-core  => [multi-core](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-core)
- multi-monitor/multi-screen => [multiple-monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors)

And now thanks to seeing it too often, the word "multi" just looks like it's spelled wrong.

Comment: How come you don't have a gem on Meta yet? I thought all Trilogy mods are weaponized here.

Comment: There's probably a probationary period. @bal

Comment: thanks, random.  watch out for the batch tagger syntax; i got gotched by it last night.